# Preact + Jest: "moduleNameMapper" and "moduleDirectories" configs not registering

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, parceljs, preact

I'm trying to set up a project with Preact, Parcel, Typescript, and Jest. I have the following in my `package.json` in order to use absolute paths for my imports:

```
"alias": {
  "src": "./src"
},
```

This lets me import my files like `import sum from 'src/math/sum';` instead of for example, `import sum from '../../../math/sum';`. This all works when actually building and running the page, but when running the tests with Jest, I get an error: `Cannot find module 'src/math/sum' or its corresponding type declarations.` After perusing other stackoverflow questions, I tried using the "moduleDirectories" and "moduleNameMapper" Jest configuration fields to make the aliases work in Jest, but the error never changed.

Here is my Jest configuration (in package.json):

```
"jest": {
    "clearMocks": true,
    "coverageDirectory": "coverage",
    "moduleDirectories": ["node_modules", "./"],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
        "^src[/](.+)": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
        "src/([^\\.]*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
    },
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "transform": {
        "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
    }
},
```

Here's my tsconfig.js:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "es6",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "jsx": "react",
        "jsxFactory": "h"                                      
    },
    "include": ["./src/**/*"]
}
```

And here are my package versions:

```
"dependencies": {
    "preact": "^10.4.4",
    "preact-router": "^3.2.1",
    "typescript": "^3.9.3"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^25.2.3",
    "jest": "^26.0.1",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.4",
    "ts-jest": "^26.0.0"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was on the right path configuring for Parcel and for Jest, the missing piece was configuring the absolute path for Typescript in tsconfig.json.

Now, with absolute paths working, my configuration is:

**package.json** (for Parcel and Jest config)

```
{
...
  "alias": {
    "src": "./src"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^src/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
    },
    "preset": "ts-jest"
  },
...
}
```

**tsconfig.json** (baseUrl and paths are the two fields that solved my problem)

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "src/*": ["./src/*"]
        }
    },
    "include": ["./src/**/*"]
}
```

Now I can import my TS files like this, assuming a file called "sum.ts" in my src directory: `import sum from 'src/sum';`